# Change time in previous row

Tags: python, pandas

I want to repeat the previous row based on a condition and change the timestamp in that new row. The new timestamp should be "a second" before the time in the next row.

The inserting a previous row part is done and the changing the time condition is set too, the problem is inserting that time in the new row.

I've attempted this using pandas.

The Input:

| a | P0 | P1 | time | Indicator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| stay | 325 | 350 | 10:59:40 | 31 |
| change | 200 | 42333 | 10:59:52 | 11 |

This is what I was thinking...

Code:

```py
cond = (df['a'] == "change") & (df['Indicator'] > 1)
idx = df.loc[cond].index - 1
idx_2 = df.loc[cond].index
s = df.timestamp.iloc[idx_2] + datetime.timedelta(seconds=-1)
df = df.append(df.loc[idx]).sort_index()
```

Here 'cond' is the condition when the new row needs to added.

So, "s" is changing the time to what I want it, and then, using "idx," I'm able to insert the new row with data from the previous row. I'm having problems with doing both at the same time. As you can see below, the timestamp for the new row in my output is not the same as required in the desired output.

The desired output is:

| a | P0 | P1 | time | Indicator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| stay | 325 | 350 | 10:59:40 | 31 |
| stay | 325 | 350 | 10:59:51 | 31 |
| change | 200 | 42333 | 10:59:52 | 11 |

But the output obtained from my code is:

| a | P0 | P1 | time | Indicator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| stay | 325 | 350 | 10:59:40 | 31 |
| stay | 325 | 350 | 10:59:40 | 31 |
| change | 200 | 42333 | 10:59:52 | 11 |

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in the code snippet which you have tried, `df.timestamp` doesn't correspond to the `time` column shown in the sample dataframe.

## Solution 1:

Building on your code, the following additions will solve the issue:

```
cond = (df['a'] == "change") & (df['Indicator'] > 1)
idx = df.loc[cond].index - 1
idx_2 = df.loc[cond].index
s = df.timestamp.iloc[idx_2] + datetime.timedelta(seconds=-1)

new_row = df.loc[idx]
new_row['timestamp'] = s.item()
df = df.append(new_row).sort_index().reset_index(drop = True)
```

The specified column is copied into 'new_row' and the required timestamp is set into it before appending in the dataframe.

## Solution 2:

Another approach would be to create a new row for every existing row where your condition is met and keep concatenating it iteratively to the original dataframe.

The following code snippet would solve the problem:

```
df2 = df #new dataframe
new_index = 0 #to keep track of index in df2 inside the loop

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    new_row = {}
    if (row['a'] == "change") and (row['Indicator'] > 1) and (i!=0):
        for column in df.columns:
            if column == 'timestamp':
                new_row[column] = row[column] + datetime.timedelta(seconds=-1)
            else:
                new_row[column] = prev_row[column]

        line = pd.DataFrame(new_row, index=[new_index])
        df2 = pd.concat([df2.iloc[:new_index,:], line, df2.iloc[new_index:,:]]).reset_index(drop=True)
        new_index+=2 #Adding 2 instead of 1 because we have added a new row to the new dataframe
    else:
        new_index+=1
    prev_row = row
```

## Output for both the approaches:

The new dataframe `df2` would look like this:

```
    a        P0  P1      timestamp          Indicator
0   stay    325 350     2021-01-31 10:59:40    31
1   stay    325 350     2021-01-31 10:59:51    31
2   change  200 42333   2021-01-31 10:59:52    11
```

Comment: Thanks Ishwar, but I think you misunderstood the question (Or I probably didn't do a good job of explaining it). The new time should be based on the condition "cond," So the new line should print the previous row with the new time based on that condtion. That is, when it says "change" and when the indicator value is above "1."                                                           Thank you for your help

Comment: Okay, as per your clarification I have edited the code slightly to accommodate the condition. Now the code adds the new row only if the condition is met. Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Assuming that the output in the question is the desired output, I am putting up two solutions. One based on your approach, and the other one being the approach I initially proposed. Feel free to use any of that and accept the answer if it solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks Ishwar, for the first solution, I'm getting an error - `ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar` Any ideas on why this may be happening?

Comment: The second solution works though, thanks!